# protobuf -net doesn’t know how to serialize datamember that are of type = object

Tags: .net, wcf, c#-4.0, protobuf-net

We have the following class as part of an ADO.NET Provider running over the wire using WCF.

```
[KnownType(typeof(AdoServiceCommandExecutionScalarResult))]
[DataContract(Namespace = Namespaces.SoafXmlNamespace)]
public class AdoServiceCommandExecutionResult
{
}
[DataContract(Namespace = Namespaces.SoafXmlNamespace)]
public class AdoServiceCommandExecutionScalarResult : AdoServiceCommandExecutionResult
{
    [DataMember]
    public object Result { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return new XDocument(new XElement(GetType().Name, new XAttribute("Result", Result))).ToString();
    }
}
```

We are trying to use protobuf-net for serialization however there is an exception thrown that the type object cannot be resolved.

Exception Message:

```
No serializer defined for type: System.Object
```

Stack Track:

```
ProtoBuf.Meta.ValueMember.BuildSerializer()
ProtoBuf.Meta.ValueMember.get_Serializer()
ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType.BuildSerializer()
ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType.get_Serializer()
ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType.ProtoBuf.Serializers.ISerializerProxy.get_Serializer()
ProtoBuf.Serializers.SubItemSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoTypeSerializer.HasCallbacks(CallbackType callbackType)
ProtoBuf.Serializers.TypeSerializer.HasCallbacks(CallbackType callbackType)
ProtoBuf.Serializers.TypeSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.EmitWrite(CompilerContext ctx, Local valueFrom)
ProtoBuf.Compiler.CompilerContext.WriteNullCheckedTail(Type type, IProtoSerializer tail, Local valueFrom)
ProtoBuf.Compiler.CompilerContext.BuildSerializer(IProtoSerializer head, TypeModel model)
ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer..ctor(IProtoTypeSerializer head, TypeModel model)
ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType.get_Serializer()
ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Serialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.TrySerializeAuxiliaryType(ProtoWriter writer, Type type, DataFormat format, Int32 tag, Object value, Boolean isInsideList)
ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.TrySerializeAuxiliaryType(ProtoWriter writer, Type type, DataFormat format, Int32 tag, Object value, Boolean isInsideList)
ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.SerializeCore(ProtoWriter writer, Object value)
ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Serialize(Stream dest, Object value, SerializationContext context)
ProtoBuf.ServiceModel.XmlProtoSerializer.WriteObjectContent(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, Object graph)
System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph)
System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObject(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, Object graph)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, PartInfo part, Object graph)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeParameter(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, PartInfo part, Object graph)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeBody(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object returnValue, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.OperationFormatterMessage.OperationFormatterBodyWriter.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.OnWriteMessage(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessageWriter.WriteMessage(Message message, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 initialOffset, Int32 maxSizeQuota)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.WriteMessage(Message message, Int32 maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 messageOffset)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.SerializeBufferedMessage(Message message)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.Send(TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline.SendReplyCore(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestContext.OnReply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContextBase.Reply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContextBase.Reply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.Reply(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
```

Is it possible to resolve this?

EDIT:
We have a custom routine that basically does (simplified for brevity).

```
type.GetAttributes<KnownTypeAttribute>().Select(a => a.Type).Distinct().ForEach(t => AddKnownTypeHierarchy(t));  

public static void AddKnownTypeHierarchy(Type type)
{

    ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType metaType = RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(type, true);
    ...
    var fieldNumber = derivedType.MetadataToken;
    metaType.AddSubType(fieldNumber, derivedType);
    ...
    var memberType = member.MemberInfo.As<PropertyInfo>().IfNotNull(p => p.PropertyType) ?? member.As<FieldInfo>().IfNotNull(f => f.FieldType);
    var field = metaType.AddField(member.Order, member.Name);
    if (memberType == typeof (object) || memberType.EqualsGenericTypeFor(typeof (IEnumerable<>))) field.DynamicType = true;
    ...
}
```

We adding logic that if an object is encountered that it should be treated as dynamic. 
That approach resulted in the following exception:

```
Dynamic type is not a contract-type: Int32
```

Is it possible to add support for treating object as dynamic instead?

Comment: Please can you report the *exact* exception message?

Comment: Edited question to include the exception message and stack trace

Comment: Is it possible to add support for treating object as dynamic instead?

Comment: there is some limited support for that, but my sincere advice would be: don't. Protobuf is intrinsically not based around type meta. It would be better to simply tell it what data you are working with on the contract API rather than using object,

Answer (score 1):

Protobuf requires a specific type to serialise/deserialise. you will need to give it something specific rather than Object.